# Are there any post BTC halving hashrate prediction markets?

Tags: hashpower, reward-schedule

Are there any futures markets that allow predictions of post BTC halving network hashrate?

Answer (score 1):

No obvious place that has this bet right now, but you can create a bet at [bitbet](https://bitbet.us). Note that you bet at your own risk, there's no actual guarantee that you'd get your bitcoins if you win.